# Spring boot ignores JSonTypeInfo in MappedSuperClass

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

Spring boot 2 rest api does not serialize mappedsuperclass inheritance.

I use Spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE and PagingAndSortingRepository. 
My appconfig is:

```
jackson:
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
    deserialization:
      FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY: true
      ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT: true
    parser:
      STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION: true
```

My mappedsuperclass is:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EmployeeUnit.class, name = "EmployeeUnit")
})
public class AbstractDomain {
  ...
}
```

Child class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = EmployeeUnit.TABLE_NAME)
@GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
    parameters =  {
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "employee_unit_seq"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1000"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
    })
 @JsonTypeName("employeeUnit")
 public class EmployeeUnit extends AbstractDomain {
 }
```

output is:

```
{
  "name" : "Unit-Pecs-EA1",
  "code" : "UPEA1",
  "description" : "Pecs EA Unit 1",
  "created" : "2019-02-10 12:34",
  "edited" : "2019-02-10 12:34",
  "_links" : {
     "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8480/api/v1/employeeUnit/1000"
  },
  "employeeUnit" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:8480/api/v1/employeeUnit/1000"
  }
}
```

Is there an other config settings to force serializing mapped super classes?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(EmployeeUnit.class);
    }
}
```